# In app purchase - how to make "Yes" button be "Buy"

Tags: objective-c, tags, uibutton, in-app-purchase, uialertview

I want to rename the "Yes" button in `UIAlertView` to be "Buy".

Here are codes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;


[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
} else {
    UIButton * buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
    [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
}

return cell;
}


- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

UIButton * buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}
```

**By far, "Buy" operation in cells does work.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    UIStoryboard    *   storyboard  =   [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SSDetailViewController * detailViewController   =   [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
} else {
    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cell Selected to Buy"
                                                         message:@"Tap \"YES\" to Confirm Purchase"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertView show];


}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"cancel");
} else {
    NSLog(@"YES");

 // **here want to make "buy" operation, but how to get `button.tag` that in the tapped cell?**      
 //SKProduct *product = _products[button.tag];
 //[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
}
}
```

here are two pictures for reference, thanks anyone who could give me a hand!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply change the string you pass for the button title?

Comment: @rmaddy, if you have a look on the comment in the source code, it becomes apparent, that OP intention is to identify what cell was pressed. he seems to be assuming that renaming would help him with that.

Comment: OK, the question is about changing the label but the comment in the code is about determining which product was chosen.

Comment: @rmaddy, I think, that OP assumes that the the same title of an button will lead to the same object? he does not really say, he want to rename it. he "wants it to be…".  so not really clear, and for sure lack of understanding of OOP and view hierarchies.

Comment: Hi guys, actually I'm leaning IAP, referring to this sample, http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial, so most of codes I put here is from that. Regarding tag issue you commented, I'm not very clear about it , just leveraging sample codes to move the tutorial forward to the function that I'm assuming. In the end, appreciated if you could advise on what I wanna do.

Comment: I can't believe that there is a such an usage of tags on raywenderlich.com. I am shocked.

Answer (score 0):

UIView's tag is not suitable for passing information around, although you see this abuse a lot.

Save the index path of the selected cell and use that when the alert button is fired. The names on the buttons do not really matter, just give it another title.

Comment: a nice article abut tag abuse: http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html

Comment: Thanks for points on tag abuse that I didn't notice as my above comment. In this case, what's the right way to revise and continue to realize my idea ?

Comment: as I said: save the selected index path in `tableView:didSelectRowWithIndexPath:` and use that in the delegate methods of UIAlertView. tags are never useful. I didn't use them once in 5 Years of professional cocoa development.